# Issue with Generic Webhook Trigger plugin in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, github

I am trying to use Generic Webhook Trigger plugin in Jenkins to trigger build in case any PR is raised on my GitHub repo. For starters I defined a variable "current_status" mapping it to "action" field within the json payload to be received from GitHub. While the build is getting triggered on raising a PR but the value for current_status is coming as null. The content-type for my GitHub webhook is "application/json"

[image: Variable inside Jenkins]

The GitHub payload generated against the PR event has action field in it :
"action": "opened",
But when I try to print this variable using println "${params.current_status}" in my pipeline, the value is printed as null.

Also when I try to execute a step based on the value of the variable using

```
when {
     expression { return params.current_status == "opened" }
}
```

the stage is skipped even though the value as per the action in the GitHub payload is "opened"

For debugging the issue when I selected the option to print the contributed variables in the job log I could see value of the current_status value as opened

[image]

But when I refer this variable in my pipeline its value comes out to be null somehow.

As a workaround made my pipeline parmeterized, using the same name for the variable as the one defined in the Generic Webhook Trigger Plugin section (current_status) and then referred to it within my Jenkinsfile and it worked.(the value for the variable reflected the value received in the json payload from GitHub).

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution. For anyone who might be facing the same issue you can refer to the variable defined within the Generic Webhook Trigger plugin directly as a Groovy variable. In my case I tried to the use the variable current_status directly without referrring it via params and it worked as expected.

The other approach of defining the variable via parmeterized pipeline might be helpful wherein we would want to run the build manually.